# Как установить cookie для субдоменов в Yii Framework?

Tags: cookie, yii

Устанавливаю cookie таким образом:

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['id'] = new CHttpCookie('id', 'info');
```

Как мне установить cookie для всех субдоменов?

Answer (score 1):

К одному домену привязываются куки.

Если куки на разных поддоменах - это не хорошо.

В твоем случае непонятно зачем это тебе нужно.